# Problems in Copying Skip List

Tags: c++, copy-constructor, skip-lists

I've encountered a problem while trying to writing a copy function for my Skip List. Since most of the class is already done, I'd prefer not to change my design.

Each node has two pointers, one to the next node on the same level, the other to the equivalent node one level below. 
In my class, there is a vector that stores pointers to the head node of each level.

```
struct Node
{
    int key;
    Node* next;
    Node* below;
}
vector<Node*> levels;
```

My private copy function:

```
void copyAll(const SkipList& s)
{
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < s.level.size(); ++i)
    {
        Node* curr = s.level[i];
        Node* copy = new Node(curr->key, nullptr, curr->below);
        level.push_back(copy);
        curr = curr->next;
        while(curr != nullptr)
        {
            copy->next = new Node(curr->key, nullptr, curr->below);
            copy = copy->next;
            curr = curr->next;
        }
    }
}
```

The function works fine horizontally with every single node copied and linked to each other, but it doesn't set up any links vertically.
`curr->below` doesn't seem right, anyone can get some suggestions how to make this work?

Comment: Learn how to use a debugger, then you can step through the code line by line while monitoring the variables and how they change values. That should help you debug your own code and see what it does and where and why it does wrong.

Comment: @Joachim Pileborg Alright, you are fast, but your universal comment doesn't make any sense..

Comment: What does `Node`'s constructor look like? Also, "will not work" isn't a very useful problem description.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of working your way down from the top levels, you could do it from the bottom up. That way, whenever you are going to create a copy of a Node, you already have a copy of its corresponding "below":

```
void copyAll(const SkipList& s)
{
    level.resize(s.level.size());
    for(unsigned int i = s.level.size(); i > 0; --i)
    {
        Node* curr = s.level[i-1]; // Note the intended change in the range of i
        Node* curBelowCopy = // If not the bottom, ptr to start of the row below
            curr->below ? level[i] : nullptr;

        Node* copy = new Node(curr->key, nullptr, curBelowCopy);
        level[i-1] = copy;
        curr = curr->next;
        while(curr != nullptr)
        {
            if (curBelowCopy) {
                // Not the last level: advance curBelowCopy to the
                // corresponding copy of cur->below
                while (curBelowCopy->key != curr->below->key)
                    curBelowCopy = curBelowCopy->next;
            }

            copy->next = new Node(curr->key, nullptr, curBelowCopy);
            copy = copy->next;
            curr = curr->next;
        }
    }
}
```